# Trying to create a new column by summing values in two other columns in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for some help in creating a new column and filling the row values with the sum four other columns in the row. I have attempted using the code below however I continually receive a type mismatch problem when trying to run it on the row:

`results(i) = SForehandRange(i, 1) + SBackhandRange(i, 1) + RForehandRange(i, 1) + RBackhandRange(i, 1)`

I'm not sure if this is the exact problem and would be grateful of any assistance.
The code is running on a table that i have already created and the values in it are numbers. Some cells will be blank however I tried filling all cells with values and still received the error.

```
Sub sumShotsInRally()

'Set rawData sheet as active
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Set sht1 = Sheets("rawData")
sht1.Activate

'Find the Columns to Add
Dim serverForehandColNum As Integer
serverForehandColNum = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(what:="Serving player forehand", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
Dim serverBackhandColNum As Integer
serverBackhandColNum = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(what:="Serving player backhand", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
Dim returnerForehandColNum As Integer
returnerForehandColNum = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(what:="Returning player forehand", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
Dim returnerBackhandColNum As Integer
returnerBackhandColNum = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(what:="Returning player backhand", lookat:=xlWhole).Column

'Insert new column for the sum total
ActiveSheet.Columns(serverForehandColNum + 1).Insert

' Add New col heading
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, serverForehandColNum + 1).Value = "Rally Count"

Dim rallyCountColNum As Integer
rallyCountColNum = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(what:="Rally Count", lookat:=xlWhole).Column

'Define the range to iterate over
Dim SForehandRange As Range
Dim SBackhandRange As Range
Dim RForehandRange As Range
Dim RBackhandRange As Range
Dim rallyRange As Range

With ActiveSheet
    Set SForehandRange = .Range(.Cells(2, serverForehandColNum), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, serverForehandColNum))
    Set SBackhandRange = .Range(.Cells(2, serverBackhandColNum), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, serverBackhandColNum))
    Set RForehandRange = .Range(.Cells(2, returnerForehandColNum), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, returnerForehandColNum))
    Set RBackhandRange = .Range(.Cells(2, returnerBackhandColNum), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, returnerBackhandColNum))
    Set rallyRange = .Range(.Cells(2, rallyCountColNum), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, rallyCountColNum))
End With

Dim results()
'You redimension the results array to the number of entries in your table
ReDim results(1 To SForehandRange.Rows.Count)
'You loop over your table and sum the values from count and restocked
For i = 1 To SForehandRange.Rows.Count
    results(i) = SForehandRange(i, 1) + SBackhandRange(i, 1) + RForehandRange(i, 1) + RBackhandRange(i, 1)
Next i
'You write the array to the range count and delete the values in restocjed
rallyRange = Application.Transpose(results)

End Sub
```

Comment: I think this would be *much* easier if you converted your table to an actual table (`ListObject`) and used a `SUM` formula with structured references.

Comment: Not tested, but i think you need `SForehandRange.Cells(i, 1)` instead of `SForehandRange(i, 1)` and same for all variables declared as `Range`. `SForehandRange(i, 1)` would be if `SForehandRange` was declared as Array, not as range.

Comment: @BigBen thanks for the reply i actually do have the table as an actual table. How would i do what you are suggesting in vba?

Comment: You would just write the formula to the `.DataBodyRange` of the `ListColumn` that you create.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns thanks for the reply but still the same error.

Comment: @BigBen i''ve attempted what you said: ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("rawData").ListObject.ListColumns("Rally").DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(rawData[Serving Player Forehand])" This still doesn't work however i get an error: object doesn't support this property or method?

Comment: A `Worksheet` doesn't have a `ListObject` property. It's `ListObjects` and you then need to specify the table index or name.